# How to declare const without an assignment but assign in a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, variable-assignment

I need to declare const `$element` (a variable pointing to `HTML` element) in global scope so that it will be able to be reached by any functions. But `$element` is assigned by `jQuery` which required variable assigned inside `$(function(){})`. How do I satisfy these two conditions?

```
const $element; // error caused by no assignment but $ is not ready
$(function(){
    const $element = $("#SomeDiv"); //cannot assign here
    DivResize(100);
});
function DivResize(h){
    $element.css("height", h) //need to call $element from global scope
}
```

Comment: There is not way doing that using `const`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution 1:**

Use `let` instead of `const`.

**Solution 2: Refactor your code a bit**

Do you really need the `DivResize()` function to be global?

**Yes:**
Make the function accept $element as argument.

```
$(function(){
    const $element = $("#SomeDiv");
    DivResize($element, 100);
});
function DivResize($element, h){
    $element.css("height", h);
}
```

**No:**
Move the function inside the jQuery callback.

```
$(function(){
    function DivResize(h){
        $element.css("height", h);
    }
    // ...
    const $element = $("#SomeDiv");
    DivResize(100);
});
```